# Javascript to dynamically format lists from items with a bullet point

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### Use case

API returns a string with something like `The ingredients are * apple* carrot *potato`. Note that the spacing between the bullet points will not often be consistent.

In the element where I am populating a long string I will only get a brief title and a list. So I want the list (the portion of the string will start with a `*`) to first get wrapped with a `<ul>` then to have every item get wrapped with an `<li>`.

---

#### Sample string

```
This is a list of sodas * Dr. Pepper *LaCroix * 7up  *sprite * Fanta * Coke Zero *Pepsi
```

#### Steps that should get executed

1. Wrap `* Dr. Pepper *LaCroix * 7up  *sprite * Fanta * Coke Zero *Pepsi` in a `<ul>`
2. Wrap individual items in a `<li>`
3. Grab the bullet point `*` and spacing between that and any character and remove it.

#### Desired innerHTML output

```
This is a list of sodas
<ul>
    <li>Dr. Pepper</li> 
    <li>LaCroix</li>
    <li>7up</li>  
    <li>sprite</li> 
    <li>Fanta</li> 
    <li>Coke Zero</li> 
    <li>Pepsi</li>
</ul>
```

---

### Demo

Current demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/bjNmNM)

Comment: This API looks suspiciously like unsanitized user-input. I'd take great care in how you process the string. For example, taking any substring from this API and assigning it to `.innerHTML` could be dangerous by introducing an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Oh, I was just browsing your demo and the returned strings are not plaintext, they're markdown format. This is a lot more involved than the question lets on.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I totally appreciate you solving way more than I anticipated. I thought I was being greedy by asking for more than this portion, so thanks for addressing the other issues in the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your application logic, you need to use `v-for` to populate the items of the recipe and transform your input string into an object with an array to pass to the renderer:

```js
function getRecipe (str) {
  var items = str.split('*').map(s => s.trim())
  return { title: items.shift(), items }
}

// in your Vue
Vue.use(VueMarkdown)
...
  recipe: getRecipe(taco.recipe)
...
```

```html
<p>
  {{ taco.recipe.title }}
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item of taco.recipe.items">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

You should also set your initial state to empty values so that the Vue doesn't throw errors during initialization:

```
data {
  taco: {
    name: '',
    condiment_name: '',
    condiment_recipe_url: '',
    recipe: { title: '', items: [] }
  }
}
```

Optionally, you can use [`vue-markdown`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-markdown) to render the markdown syntax.

Comment: Ohhhh learning about `https://unpkg.com/vue-markdown@2.2.4/dist/vue-markdown.js` totally helped for my specific actual use case. thank you so much.

Comment: By the way, the `title` (text before `<ul>`) is not displaying https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/bjNmNM

Comment: @JGallardo notice if you remove the `<vue-markdown>` wrapping `{{ taco.recipe.title }}` it seems to have loaded fine. You'll probably need to browse [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-markdown) to see if there's something you need to customize, or look for any related [issues](https://github.com/miaolz123/vue-markdown/issues). If you can't find an answer from these resources, you might want to create an issue and provide your example to see if the author of the module can help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "This is a list of sodas * Dr. Pepper *LaCroix * 7up  *sprite * Fanta * Coke Zero *Pepsi";

//split string into an array using * as delimiter
var items = str.split('*');
//grab the first item since it's the title, not a soda
var title = items.shift();

//create an html string var
var html = `${title}<ul>`
//loop over remaining array elements and append to our html
items.forEach((el) => {
  html += `<li>${el.trim()}</li>`;
});
html += '</ul>';

//display as HTML
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to split string and then generate desired html

```js
const s = 'This is a list of sodas * Dr. Pepper *LaCroix * 7up  *sprite * Fanta * Coke Zero *Pepsi';

let chunks = s.split(/\ ?\*\ ?/);


const heading = chunks[0];

chunks = chunks.slice(1);

let output = `${heading}
  <ul>
  ${chunks.map(c => `<li>${c}</li>`).join('\n')}
  </ul>
`;

console.log(output);
```